# Is there a simple/quick fix for upgrading from PHP5.2 to PHP5.4?

Tags: php, upgrade, deprecated, register-globals

My website goes off-line when I upgrade to PHP5.4 and my host 1&1 says they are doing away with 5.2 compatibility.  I don't have the money to hire a professional to fix my website (one place quoted me at least 25 hours = $500), but I am just capable enough to insert a few lines of code in one of the files.

Is there a simple fix (workaround) to keep my website up and running that may not be technically correct or secure, but at least have it function until I can gather the money to have it done professionally?

For example, I saw this "MacGuyver-like" "fix" [PHP 5.4 hasn't register_globals anymore - That's my workaround for this.](http://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/16npyi/php_54_hasnt_register_globals_anymore_thats_my/)  --- which looks highly insecure to me.

Comment: What errors does your application generate under 5.4? Does it _depend_ on register_globals?

Comment: not recommended, but you could find a host that still supports 5.2 and move

Comment: 25 hours = $500 isn't expensive - sounds like a Student did that job

Comment: @Philipp Nope, it's dirt cheap for web development. But you get what you pay for.

Comment: I just get a blank white screen when I enter my website address in browser.  Someone told me there is an error log somewhere.  Should I call my host company for it?  I will go search on filezilla right now and see if it has register_globals

Comment: SynapseIndia gave me that quote, but that's just deposit.  They said it could be more when they actually start working.

Comment: in common you have a ftp Directory called log, which contains a file error.log - inside this file should be a detailed error log.

Comment: what's the site? is it custom build? or some open source script?

Comment: It would probably be better to find another host that still supports 5.2 and then take your time (or someone else's) refactoring code that still uses php4 functions.

Comment: "may not be technically correct or secure" is scary, as security should always be a huge concern with web applications. I hope you're not storing any personal information about your users.

Comment: To migrate from 5.2 to 5.4 - take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration53.incompatible.php and after that http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration54.incompatible.php

Comment: I have a file called php.ini (configuration settings file type) in my main directory and it says "register_globals = 'off'" so I guess not if it is actually working.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone helping me alot!!!  this was open-source software called Osdate http://www.tufat.com/s_free_dating_system.htm  the developer told me to: Basically, you will require to change all definitions of &= or =& to =.
e.g. $abc =& $xyz will need to be changed to $abc = $xyz. This will increase memory usage. This is specially required when there are data being returned by functions which are referenced.  continued on next comment ->

Comment: YOu may need to check all errors and rectify some of the deprecated code and replace with new definitions in PHP for same deprecated code.You will require to see all programs one by one. Ensure you have updated all PEAR libraries to newer ones." <-but this fix is out of my league.

Comment: yes, the world needs another poorly coded dating site ;). Funny that the code site says "PHP 4.3.0 or higher"

Comment: I did find a "logs" directory in my ftp, but it did not contain error.log

Comment: It's free to use at least - i figure I'm doing a community service for high school students.

Comment: trying the time zone fix right now!

Comment: time zone fix did not work - still crashed

Comment: Please see as well: [Why is REGISTER_GLOBALS so bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1417373/367456) and other related material.