# Is there no need to use $_GET['varName'] when using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just wrote a htaccess file and a simple rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{4})/?$ /run/run.php?country=$1&year=$2 [NC,L]
This does http://www.localhost/us/2014
```

On the php page, I accidently did:

```
echo $country.' '.$year;
```

This gave me the output below, which is correct.

```
us 2014
```

I did not do:

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
$year = $_GET['year'];
```

But it still worked. Is this normal behaviour. Can I use this for the rest of the rules and the site? I'm using WAMP on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: Could it be that you unpack the $_GET array somewhere? This shouldn't work as far as I know, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might have turned on `register_globals` in php.ini. Thats why you are getting variable with the name of array index (Here `$_GET`). It is not a best practice to turn on `register_globals`.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417373/why-is-register-globals-so-bad), why register_globals is bad.

Comment: Will turning `register_globals` off prevent me from using `global` inside functions? Eg: function foo{ global $userName; echo $userName;}?

Comment: @jmenezes: No. It will not make any problem with the your global variables.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this has nothing common with .htaccess. What PHP gets is the second part of ReWrite rule, so `$_GET` variables should be accessible. The server gets `http://www.localhost/us/2014` and the PHP gets `/run/run.php?country=us&year=2014`

As nauphal wrote this might be (probably is) the register_globals issue.

Comment: It's on on my local machine, but not on the server.

Comment: Yes this is a server. When you type a `http://localhost/something` it is like your browser connects "outside" your computer with the server program, WAMP in this case. Both share the same PC. So your machine is a server and a client in the same moment, but different programs handle this. Browser is client, WAMP is server, and PHP is something that helps the server.

Comment: Actually, I meant `the server at the hosting company`. I was trying to say its `on` on my local machine, but it's `off` on the hosting server (the one thats with the hosting company). I just checked their php info file.

Comment: So your machine server has register_globals = on and the hosting company server has register_globals = off? So turn it off on your WAMP and it's ok.