# PHP $_REQUEST server setting

Tags: php, request

I'm currently in the process of migrating servers.

My old server accepted GET/POST variables without defining them, for example:

```
$model_id = $model_id;
```

But on my new server, variables needs to be defined, eg:

```
$model_id = $_REQUEST['model_id'];
```

I'm trying to save time without having to rewrite all existing scripts, is there a quick solution?

Comment: which server accepts the variable without defining methods?

Comment: yes there is. the setting is called register_globals. you dont want to do it tho - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417373/why-is-register-globals-so-bad

Comment: thank you. I figured would not be secure, but will speed migration until scripts may be edited.

Comment: you can also use extract where required - to prevent enabling register_globals in general: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php