# Website exploited, suspected SQL injection + PHP check bypassed, but can't explain how the latter was performed

Tags: mysql, php, exploit

**Background**:

A website I made some year ago has been recently attacked; the exploiters managed to get access to the PHP front-end I made for the client, which is used to upload files, and they managed to upload some PHP files containing an exploit among other things like a PHP-based file manager. I can post the content of each uploaded PHP file if of interest, however the problem is of course that they managed to gain access to the client's front end.

The site hasn't been updated since it was first made (it uses old and deprecated MySQL functions and no `mysql_real_escape_string()` to check the inputs in the login panel (I know)), however I'm not totally sure that it's through a SQL injection that they managed to gain access.

The vhost runs on Windows / Parallels Plesk and I don't have neither SSH access nor access to the logs: I've opened a ticket with the hosting provider asking for the logs, however I'm not sure if they can provide them and how much it will take to do so, so to not risk anything more in the meantime I'm trying to exploit the suspected flaw myself.

I'm able to perform an injection in the SQL statement used to retrieve the user's data to bypass the user check, however I'm unable to break the password check immediately after, which is done in PHP.

**TL;DR**

The following is the relevant snippet used to retrieve the user data and to check the password: I'm able to perform an injection in the SQL statement (e.g. using `" OR ""="` as the username), however I'm unable to break the password check immediately after:

```php
<?PHP
// ...
else {
    $query='SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="' . $username . '";';
    $query_result=mysql_query($query);
    if(!$query_result) {
        die (mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $user_data=mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
        if($user_data && $user_data['password']==$password) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_data['id'];
            $_SESSION['user_username']=$user_data['username'];
            $_SESSION['user_password']=$user_data['password'];
            $_SESSION['user_privileges']=$user_data['privileges'];
            session_write_close();
            $next_page='control_panel.php';
        }
        else {
            $next_page='login.php?notify=username_password_wrong';
        }
    }
}
mysql_close($mysql_connect);
// ...
?>
```

Is breaking such check feasible? Or am I totally wrong on my suspicions and I should look elsewhere to find the weak spot?

Comment: it seems the passwords are stored in the db in clear text. Also you say you are able to retrieve the user data, were you able to retrieve the user passwords too?

Comment: @PetterH Yes, passwords are stored in clear text, another issue to take care of. No I'm not able to retrieve the user's data, I'm able to force the query to return the full table. This effectively has the effect of bypassing the first test in the `if($user_data && $user_data['password']==$password) {[...]}` conditional (i.e. no real need for an existing username in order to login). The problem is I don't understand how the immediately following password check could have been broken (given that that's really what happened).

Comment: why would the check need to be broken if the password was readily available to the one exploiting the system has full access to the table, he or she could just log in with any of the passwords found there?

Comment: @PetterH The table is not available to the exploiter, the exploiter can avoid to provide an existing username e.g. by inputting `" OR ""="` in the username field in the login form (which makes the actual query run as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="" OR ""="";`, which has the effect of returning the whole table and hence to make the exploiter pass the `$user_data` test in the `if() {[...]}` conditional).

Comment: Since I'm *quite* sure (altough not totally sure) that the exploit itself has been loaded through the upload form in the client's PHP front-end (mainly because of the position of the uploaded PHP files), I *guess* that whoever exploited the site managed to break both the username check (which I was able to break as well) and the password check (which I wasn't unable to break, possibly mainly because I'm not really an expert in this field (and hence why I'm asking)).

Comment: However I'm not sure of this, again my expertise is very limited, I hope for someone to be able to tell me whether having break the login system like that is something actually feasible (and perhaps how) or that my efforts are wasted in investigating this because the password check it's actually ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @MadHatter I wouldn't call this a duplicate. He has a specific scenario with specific code that he is evaluating for security holes. A generic "How do I deal with a compromised server?" isn't what he's asking.

Comment: @ElliotB. the duplicate is a **canonical** question.  On the subject of compromised servers the community has said all it is going to say, because although everyone's particular problems in that class are somewhat different, to the extent that they are interesting, they aren't different, and to the extent that they're different, they aren't interesting (to anyone save the questioner). So we write one answer that's designed to be the last word on the subject, and say no more.  But others may not agree with me, and if they don't, this question won't get closed.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

The password check via the `if` statement is not sufficient. With the SQL injection and access to the source of your authentication script, they have everything they need for full access.

**Long answer:**

We've already established that your auth script is vulnerable to SQL injection. You also describe the code as very old and unchanged. From this it is reasonable to assume that the web server running this application is also old and outdated.

If you have `register_globals` enabled on this server, then it would be very easy to set the `$_SESSION` values directly -- bypassing your `if` statement password check. It would be as simple as submitting a GET request with the following URI: `site.php?_SESSION[user_id]=12345`.

If the hackers were able to upload their own PHP files, then they were certainly able to obtain the full code of your authentication script and determine if `register_globals` is enabled.

[**Further reading**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417373/why-is-register-globals-so-bad) on security implications of `register_globals`.

This is just one possible way they could have fully compromised your application. But honestly, if they used SQL injection to obtain credentials on all users **and** they had executable files uploaded to your account, then there are a billion ways they could have fully compromised your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's a point, cardinal to your reasoning, which I don't understand: how would they have got access to the source authentication script? The injection looks useful only to pass the first test and no user data is ever returned from the script: all the script does is setting some session variables and redirecting to another page, so how would they have bypassed the test? Your point about `register_globals` makes sense tough, I'll check this out as soon as I can. Thanks so far

Comment: @kos If the hackers were able to upload a PHP file manager type script and if PHP commands like `shell_exec` are enabled on your server, then that means they essentially had a bash login to your server. Reading the source of your authentication script, would've been as simple as: `cat /home/username/path/to/your/auth/script.php`

Comment: Bear with me if I'm not understanding something, but the snippet I posted is from a login page I made for the client to login and to get access to a sort of control panel including various functions, such as one to upload files in a specific folder (*the folder in which I found the exploit*). My question is: since from the position of the exploit is very likely that the attackers uploaded it using the upload function in the user's control panel, this means they probably somehow got access to the control panel. [cont]

Comment: [cont] The snippet I posted is the relevant section of the login page; I myself found out that the username check performed in order to give access to the control panel it's easily bypassable using injection, but *how could they have break the password check*? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @kos "how could they have break the password check?" As from above, they likely "broke" it by bypassing it. Regarding viewing the source code, if they were able to upload an executable PHP script to your web space, then they could have traversed anywhere they wanted to within the account (and possibly elsewhere depending upon which system user their PHP scripts are executed as). There is nothing stopping them from moving from the directory containing the login code to the directory containing the control panel code.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for the confusion, I was mislead a bit by this sentence: "With the SQL injection and access to the source of your authentication script [...]", in which I read the "access to the source of your authentication" as a requisite to break the script. So, in a nutshell, you are saying that one possibility is they have abused `register_globals` in order to fake a login, upload the script, execute the exploit and gain a root shell correct?

Comment: In any case the domain has been temporarily disabled upon my request by the provider, I'll make sure to check if `register_globals` is actually enabled as soon as it gets re-enabled.

Comment: @kos They don't need access to the source code before trying to hack it. From the login form it is easy to guess the internal variables; if your input field is labeled 'username', there's a 99% chance your PHP variable is also called $username. Combine that with a very logical tablename (users) and column (username) it only takes a few tries before they discover the proper SQL injection. No source code required.

Answer (score 0):

While not an exhaustive list, here are a few ways to bypass the php password check:

1) Use the SQL injection payload of `" union select '<?php system($_GET[cmd]); ?>',2,3,etc into outfile '/var/www/shell.php' --` which will create a backdoor and then fail the authentication check. The attacker can now just browse directly to shell.php

2) Use error based SQL injection to retrieve the content of the user table and then use the plain text credentials to login.

3) Use a union query to return static values and for the username and password fields `" union select 1,'password',privileges,etc from users --`

This is of course assuming this was the actual attack vector.